# WPF - Windows Azure Style TabControl(?)

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm looking for a control similar to the one in the picture as found on Azure but for WPF.

I'm just wondering if this is a premade control (either from MS, or someone else?) which can be used in WPF or code to start such a project. I have tried a tabcontrol, but it doesn't do the sliding blades.

[image]

Comment: I am afraid there is no premade control as far as I know, you can call it **nav expander**(from html source code), and I think it's not difficult impl by youself :)

Comment: I was thinking the same, pretty easy to implement with stackpanels and togglebuttons :) - maybe ill create the control for all to use :) - time will tell

Comment: Hi, in absence of any available solution, I went ahead and implemented the above Azure Management portal navigation style using ListBoxes in WPF. 

You can view the final result of the style here ->

http://arbitrarybytes.blogspot.in/2014/05/azure-portal-navigation-style-in-wpf.html

Since the question was closed I could not directly paste the styles here. But the xaml file is available here ->

http://goo.gl/LB5IT8

Hope this helps and feel free to comment on the blog post for any improvements and suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

Surely the control in your image is just a `Menu` control that has a custom `ControlTemplate`. We can give the `Menu` control a new `ItemsPanelTemplate` to make it work vertically instead of the usual horizontal look. Unfortunately I don't have time to complete this, but I've started you off:

```
<Menu FontFamily="Segoe UI" Background="#FF3C454F" TextElement.Foreground="White">
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical"/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    <Menu.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="40, 20" />
        </Style>
    </Menu.Resources>
    <MenuItem Header="COMPUTER">
        <MenuItem Header="WEBSITE" />
        <MenuItem Header="VIRTUAL MACHINE" />
        <MenuItem Header="MOBILE SERVICE" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="DATA SERVICES">
        <MenuItem Header="WEBSITE" />
        <MenuItem Header="VIRTUAL MACHINE" />
        <MenuItem Header="MOBILE SERVICE" />
    </MenuItem>
    <MenuItem Header="NETWORK SERVICES">
        <MenuItem Header="WEBSITE" />
        <MenuItem Header="VIRTUAL MACHINE" />
        <MenuItem Header="MOBILE SERVICE" />
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

There's still lots for you to do though... the most important part will be to define a new `ControlTemplate` the `Menu` and the `MenuItem`s. You'll need to move the next level of `MenuItem`s from the current `Popup` control to the next column in a `Grid`.

The best way to start this job is to use the default `ControlTemplate` and then 'tweak' it to your liking once you have it working as normal. You can find the default `ControlTemplate` in the [Menu Styles and Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752296%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN. Another resource can be found on the [MenuItem ControlTemplate Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms747082%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) page, although it might have the same code, I'm not quite sure.

One final point I'd like to make is that if this project proves to be too difficult for you, you could probably make your UI look like your image using a number of `ListBox` controls, where the items represent the menu items. It would be quite easy to change the items dependant on the previous menu item that the user clicked on.